# Signals are not always seen by all children in a process group

Tags: python, ruby, bash, process, signals

I have a problem with the way signals are propagated within a process group. Here is my situation and an explication of the problem :

I have an application, that is launched by a shell script (with a su). This shell script is itself launched by a python application using subprocess.Popen
I call os.setpgrp as a preexec_function and have verified using ps that the bash script, the su command and the final application all have the same pgid.

Now when I send signal USR1 to the bash script (the leader of the process group), sometimes the application see this signal, and sometimes not. I can't figure out why I have this random behavior (The signal is seen by the app about 50% of the time)

Here is he example code I am testing against :

Python launcher :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
p = subprocess.Popen( ["path/to/bash/script"], stdout=…, stderr=…, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp )
# loop to write stdout and stderr of the subprocesses to a file
# not that I use fcntl.fcntl(p.stdXXX.fileno(), fcntl.F_SETFL, os.O_NONBLOCK)
p.wait()
```

Bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
set -u

cd /usr/local/share/gios/exchange-manager

CONF=/etc/exchange-manager.conf
[ -f $CONF ] && . $CONF

su exchange-manager -p -c "ruby /path/to/ruby/app"
```

Ruby application :

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
Signal.trap("USR1") do
    puts "Received SIGUSR1"
    exit
end

while true do
    sleep 1
end
```

So I try to send the signal to the bash wrapper (from a terminal or from the python application), sometimes the ruby application will see the signal and sometimes not. I don't think it's a logging issue as I have tried to replace the puts by a method that write directly to a different file.

Do you guys have any idea what could be the root cause of my problem and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signal handler is doing too much. If you exit from within the signal handler, you are not sure that your buffers are properly flushed, in other words you may not be exiting gracefully your program. Be careful of new signals being received when the program is already inside a signal handler.

Try to modify your Ruby source to exit the program from the main loop as soon as an "exit" flag is set, and don't exit from the signal handler itself.

Your Ruby application becomes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$done = false
Signal.trap("USR1") do
    $done = true
end

until $done do
    sleep 1
end

puts "** graceful exit"
```

Which should be much safer.

For real programs, you may consider using a Mutex to protect your flag variable.